# NW.js not clearing cache correctly

Tags: javascript, module, nw.js

**Environment**

- NW.js v0.12.3 (32 bits)
- Windows 8
- [Webchimera.js](https://github.com/jaruba/wcjs-player) (player) VLC Build (2.2.1)
- [require-new](https://github.com/gajus/require-new)

**Problem**

New window is opened from parent window. **Webchimera** module is loaded but it crashes because its **window** object points to parent window. That is because NW.js [caches its modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching).

**PARENT**

```
<div id="chimera_container"></div>

...
var gui; // global variable for parent object
var wjs; // global variable for parent object
....
gui = require('nw.gui');
wjs = wjs = require('wcjs-player');
....
video_emit = gui.Window.open('video_emit.html',{
    "window" : {
        "focus": true,
        "toolbar": true,
        "frame": true,
        "width" : 640,
        "height" : 640
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "require-new": "^1.1.0",
        "wcjs-player": "^0.5.6"
    },  
});
```

**video_emit window**

```
<div id="vid"></div>

....
var wjs; // global variable for new window object
wjs = require('wcjs-player');  
video_container = new wjs("#vid"); <---- CRASHES **** !!!
```

In the **node_modules\wcjs-player\index.js line 82** I added

```
console.log(window.document);
```

**PARENT CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
#document
...
<div id="chimera_container"></div>
```

**video_emit CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
#document
...
<div id="chimera_container"></div>
```

**Solutions tried**

*Manually clearing cache*

Calling function **clearRequiredModules** before requiring *'wcjs-player'* module on *video_emit window*.

```
var clearRequiredModules = function(){
    // clear wcjs-player from require cache to force new load
    var clearModules = [
        "wcjs-player",
        "jquery" // https://github.com/jaruba/wcjs-player/issues/38
    ];
    for (var i in clearModules) {
        for (var module in global.require.cache) {
            if ( global.require.cache.hasOwnProperty(module) 
                 && module.indexOf(clearModules[i]) > -1
                )
                delete global.require.cache[module];
        }
    }
};
```

Not working. Same problem as if I hadn't cleared at all. Still points to parent window object.

*Using require-new module*

There's no science to this code, I load module and use it in **video_emit window**.

```
var req_new = require('require-new');
wjs = req_new('wcjs-player');
```

Still crashes.

---

I know that adding ** new-instance: true** to the `gui.Window.open` of the parent would fix this, but I need parent and new window to communicate via the **global** variable usable only if they are on the same render.

------------------------ **Solution** -----------------------------------------

Clearing cache on its own didn't work, in order for it to be valid the following had to be done from the *parent* window.

```
video_emit = gui.Window.open('video_emit.html',{
    ...
});
video_emit .on('document-start', function() {
    video_emit .reload(3);
});
```

And in the child window:

```
clearRequiredModules(); //Same code as protrayed above
wjs = require('wcjs-player');  
video_container = new wjs("#vid");
```

***PROBLEM***

BEWARE, doing this renders the **global** variable (the one used to share information between windows, useless. So it's the same as doing this in *parent window* (and not clearing cache in child window):

```
video_emit = gui.Window.open('video_emit.html',{
        "window" : {
            "focus": true,
            "toolbar": true,
            "frame": true,
            "width" : 640,
            "height" : 640
        },
        "new-instance" : true // <---- That right there
    });
```

A possible solution to this problem is to use **localStorage** instead, to communicate between windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wcjs-player` is heavily reliant on being able to access `window.document`. `NW.js` v0.12.3 has a bug that leaks the parent's `window` object to the child window.

I've seen this create numerous issues including pushing all errors and logs to the main window, and it always breaks all modules that are dependent on `window`.

The fix for this is to do a node.js level reload of the child window after creating it.

[Proof of Concept](http://webchimera.org/samples/nw.js-0.12.3-new-window-poc.zip)

[Discussion](https://github.com/jaruba/wcjs-player/issues/44)

**Example Usage:**

```
var new_win = require('nw.gui').Window.open('index.html');
new_win.on('document-start', function() {
    new_win.reload(3);
});
```

**Notes:**

- It should also be mentioned that this is a `NW.js` specific issue, `Electron` does not have this issue with new windows.
- As this is a high level page reload, the `global` object will also be cleared, an alternative solution to passing information to this new window is using `localStorage` (that is persistent), or for more complex needs websockets.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I'm giving Electron a try right now to see if I should switch over. If you add to this answer the fact that you lose ability to interact via the global variable I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try just "touching" all your js files on your server. "Clearing cache" is not as easy as it should be. Instead of clearing cache on my browsers, I realized that "touching" the server files cached will actually change the date and time of the source file cached on the server (Tested on Edge, Chrome and Firefox) and most browsers will automatically download the most current fresh copy of whats on your server (code, graphics any multimedia too). I suggest you just copy the most current scripts on the server and "do the touch thing" solution before your program runs, so it will change the date of all your problem files to a most current date and time, then it downloads a fresh copy to your browser:

```
 <?php
    touch('/www/sample/file1.js');
    touch('/www/sample/file2.js');
    touch('/www/sample/file2.js');
 ?>
```

then ... the rest of your program...

It took me some time to resolve this issue (as many browsers act differently to different commands, but they all check time of files and compare to your downloaded copy in your browser, if different date and time, will do the refresh), If you can't go the supposed right way, there is always another usable and better solution to it. Best Regards and happy camping. By the way touch(); or alternatives work in many programming languages inclusive in javascript bash sh php and you can include or call them in html.